# Accessing response of xmlHttpRequest giving error

Tags: jquery, xmlhttprequest

I am running a xmlHttpRequest. Response of the request is an object which has name values pairs in it. One of the name value pairs looks like this:

```
"actor":{id:"", ed:""}
```

I am trying to access this name value pair in response. But I am not able to. I am doing it like this.

```
 var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.withCredentials = true;

xhr.addEventListener("readystatechange", function () {
    var thaaat = this;
    if (this.readyState === 4) {
        let resp = xhr.responseText
        console.log(JSON.parse(xhr.responseText).actor.id)
        let id;
        if(document.getElementById("occupation-input").value.toUpperCase() === "POLITICIAN"){
            id = thaaat.response.politician.id
        }
        else if(document.getElementById("occupation-input").value.toUpperCase() === "ACTOR"){
            id = thaaat.response.actor.id
        }
        console.log("success")
        that.afterFaceAdded(id);
    }
});

xhr.open("POST",url);
xhr.setRequestHeader("authorization", "Token " + that.props.token_Reducer.token);
xhr.setRequestHeader("content-type", "application/json");
//xhr.setRequestHeader("cache-control", "no-cache");
//xhr.setRequestHeader("postman-token", "87ea9499-816d-f5e6-ae2b-f190bc268b79");

xhr.send(data);
```

However it is giving me an error saying:

> AddTagSection.js:268 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined
>           at XMLHttpRequest.eval

Response looks like this

[image]

Comment: If the response is JSON you'll need to parse it to an object. Try `JSON.parse(xhr.responseText).actor.id`

Comment: Made an edit. It is an object. Not a json

Comment: How are you deserialising it? Your code is not showing that, and it's not an automatic behaviour.

Comment: I am not doing it. Also look at the image I attached in edit. How should I access actor.id?

Comment: If that's your response, then what you had should work. Can you show a *complete* sample of your AJAX request logic, as you seem to only be showing pieces of it./

Comment: Sure. I have added the full request code

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/168645/discussion-between-apurvg-and-rory-mccrossan).